# PhPMyAdmin - Allow SSO and Keep Tracking

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a situation in my company. We are current running a RHEL 7 with PhpMyAdmin (PMA), MySQL and JupyterHub (JH) installed. Users access the JH SSL site and authenticate with unix credentials (by auth_socket). The same users can authenticate on MySQL trhough the same socket, by login MySQL without password (by auth_socket). The point is: users on 80 port (PhpMyAdmin) cannot connect without password (even if I allow this feature, any user could use other username). And they cannot user unix credentials on PhpMyAdmin (because MySQL uses auth_socket, only allowing to login by user session).

I don't know what to do to allow users login to PMA !! Any help is aprecciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, phpMyAdmin doesn't currently support logging in through auth_socket connections (you can see https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16118 for details).

Basically, since phpMyAdmin runs as the webserver user account, there isn't a way to change the user or authenticate that the user is who they claim to be. I imagine it is unlikely that this will be able to be implemented in a web-based application like phpMyAdmin.

The closest approximation I can suggest is that you might be able to come up with something relating to the [signon authentication type](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#signon-authentication-mode), but you'll still have to change your user (or create a second user account) to connect via socket or TCP/IP connection.